# How do I stop using OneDrive as my default "Documents" location on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, file-association, onedrive, default-settings

I'm on Windows 10 and today I had to look for a file which I knew was in "Documents". However, when I browsed to the directory `C:\Users\MyUser\Documents` I didn't find the folder, the folder was in my OneDrive folder which was at `C:\Users\MyUser\OneDrive\Documents`.
And the program that I used (Netbeans) saved files to the onedrive folder while I never explicitly told Netbeans to do so.

How would I go about disabling OneDrive or make sure I don't save files to the OneDrive folder?
Is there a way to easily transfer all my files from the OneDrive folder to the original Documents folder?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you log in with a local account or a Microsoft account?

Comment: @DrZoo With a Microsoft account. I don't need it, though, so if I somehow can unlink the account from my computer and it solves this problem I can live with that.

Comment: Well I just posted an answer. So you can either do that, or I can help you revert to a local account

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unlink my Documents folder from my OneDrive account?](https://superuser.com/questions/1205668/how-to-unlink-my-documents-folder-from-my-onedrive-account)

Answer (score 0):

**Switching from Microsoft Account to a Local Account**

Go to the start menu search bar and type `Accounts`. In the window that pops up, select the 'Your Account' tab on the left hand side. You will see a link that says `Sign in with a local account instead`.

After selecting that, it will make you verify your Microsoft account by entering your password. It will then prompt you for `Local Account` credentials, such as a user name and a password (the password might be optional), then click `Next`. This will bring you to a final page where it will have you click on `Sign out an finish` of the Microsoft account, then have you log in as a local account.

Note: Before doing the `Sign out and finish`, make sure save any important work.

Comment: Before I do this I have one question: what will this do to the existing files in the onedrive folder?

Comment: That I'm not 100% sure about. I would move them to a local folder before doing this. They should still be there after disabling it, but I wouldn't take any chances.

Comment: Alright, so to be safe I backed the files up to a local folder. Then I went ahead and enabled that policy. I rebooted my computer and to test the functionality I opened up Netbeans and created a new folder, in the pane it still used the onedrive folder.. So unfortuantely it does't work. I don't exactly know how Netbeans comes up with the save location, I can't find it anywhere in the settings. Do you have a clue how it's still not working? Again, if removing the Microsoft account is quicker/easier I'm perfectly fine with that.

Comment: Did you check to see if the `C:\Users\MyUser\OneDrive\Documents` still exists? Or is it now `C:\Users\MyUser\Documents`

Comment: The Onedrive folder `C:\Users\MyUser\OneDrive\Documents` still exists. I also see the folder in the file explorer.

Comment: Ok give me a sec, and I'll post how to switch to local account

Comment: @JimmyDG updated the answer.

Comment: Alright so I did that but I still have the whole OneDrive folder. When I try to remove the onedrive folder from the "Your Account" window and then restart, it pops up again. Do you have any idea how I can completely remove the Microsoft account from my computer?

Comment: That should completely remove it. Did you also disable OneDrive at Startup? You can also change the path for the `Documents` folder. If you open Windows Explorer and right click on `Documents` then select `Properties` you can point it to a different default location.

Comment: Yes, I have already removed OneDrive from startup. I can only right click on the local My Documents folder and set its location, when I right click on the OneDrive documents folder I don't see a tab called "location". So now I have 2 accounts, a local account and a Microsoft account the latter which I'm not able to remove. And I still have the Onedrive folder, is there anything else I can do to get rid of the MS account thus removing the Onedrive integration?

Comment: If you go back to `Accounts` and go to the bottom of the page, it should show `Other Accounts You Use`. Can you right click on the `Other Account` and remove it? Like so - http://imgur.com/k1mQnTd

Comment: I did that: http://i.imgur.com/IrNNDH8.png when I click remove, it dissapears but when I reboot it pops up again.

Comment: That's really weird because on mine it disappeared and never came back

Comment: I think when I configured Netbeans I somehow selected a folder inside Onedrive instead of my local storage. I eventually solved this by first setting everything back how it was (MS account) and moving all my projects inside Netbeans (one by one..) to my local location. However, now whenever I boot up my laptop it says that the password is incorrect  (it tries to login to the local account I created, but deleted). So now I have to manually switch to the MS account and login again. Is there a way to remove the account from the lock screen? Anyway, thanks a lot for all the suggestions.